# In docker how to create a service using Rest API?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, swarm, docker-api

I just want to create a service using docker. i created using command line but i didn't find rest call for doing the same . regret if its a silly question please do help i am a beginer

Comment: Which base image are you using? Did you add any application yourself?

Comment: i am using ubuntu 12.4 image i have installed Docker Version 1.12.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `docker` command line calls into the [Docker Remote API](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/api/docker_remote_api_v1.24/) - which is a REST API that you can use yourself. The API listens on a Unix socket, but the docs tell you how to expose it via TCP as well.

You can make direct HTTP calls to do anything the command line does, e.g. managing containers:

```
POST /containers/create ...
POST /containers/e90e34656806/start
```

And there are high-level client libraries various languages, like [Go](https://github.com/fsouza/go-dockerclient) and [.NET](https://github.com/Microsoft/Docker.DotNet).

Comment: Thanks Elton from your reference i found exactly what i need.